# Forest Coverage - European free GIS datasets

Tags: data, forest-ecology, environmental-monitoring

Where can I find GIS data for the Forest coverage for the entire Europe? Is there such a product available for free?

I am looking for raster or vector (polygons) with the information of the % of coverage by raster cell or polygon.

Comment: Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI) http://edit.csic.es/Soil-Vegetation-LandCover.html

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Corine Land Cover which covers all Europe (version 2006 does not include greece for some reason)

Its availabe in [raster](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/corine-land-cover-2000-raster-2) and in [Vector](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/corine-land-cover-2000-clc2000-seamless-vector-database-4) format

All the Classes starting from 31 are forestry:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are several products derived from satellite imagery available from the [Global Land Cover Facility (GLCF)](http://glcf.umd.edu/data/).  The following products from GLCF may be of interest to you:

[AVHRR Continuous Fields Tree Cover Product](http://glcfapp.glcf.umd.edu:8080/esdi/index.jsp)

> These data products are available on a global scale or in continetal
>   subsets in either Goode's or Lat/Long. Each product contains an
>   overall treecover data file and files separated according to the
>   following tree cover types: broadleaf, deciduous, evergreen, and
>   needle leaf.

[image]

[MODIS, 500m, 32-Day Global Composites](http://glcfapp.glcf.umd.edu:8080/esdi/index.jsp)

> Composites were derived from the MOD09A1 eight-day surface reflectance
>   product. MODIS bands 1 through 7 (red, NIR, green, blue, SWIR, SWIR,
>   SWIR) are available in single band GeoTIFF files in continental
>   subsets. These composites were used to derive the MODIS Vegetation
>   Continous Fields product.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The European Commission's Joint Research Centre produced two pan-European forest cover maps derived from optical satellite imagery for the reference years of 2000 and 2006. The 2006 version also includes a forest type (broadleaf/coniferous) classification (see map below).

All data are freely available for download as GeoTIFFs from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190130015700/http://forest.jrc.ec.europa.eu:80/download/data/forest-data-download/). More detailed information concerning the methodology of the 2006 forest maps is available [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5963712)

[image: European Forest Type Map (2006)]